# Error loading getstream with php

Tags: getstream-io

I have followed the instructions in the documentation of getstream.io but i am still getting this error.

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\getstreamtest/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\getstreamtest\test.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\getstreamtest/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\getstreamtest\test.php on line 3
```

I have included the current version of getstream. And according to the brief documentation, that should be enough. It says "Composer will take care of the autoloading for you, so if you require the vendor/autoload.php, you're good to go."

```
{
"require": {
    "get-stream/stream": "2.2.9"
}
}
```

It's not working. Any solution to this?

Comment: the path to `vendor/autoload.php` is not correct, you mixed forward and backward slashes

Comment: Yes, Composer will take care, but you first need to load composer's `autoload.php` file and **No such file or directory** says you didn't manage to.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to install composer.But this solved the problem

```
"config": { 
"secure-http": false 
}
```

Thanks